# Chunk a Ruby array according to streaks within it

Tags: ruby

**Summary:** The basic question here was, I've discovered, whether you can pass a code block to a Ruby array which will actually reduce the contents of that array down to another array, not to a single value (the way **inject** does).  The short answer is "no".

I'm accepting the answer that says this.  Thanks to Squeegy for a great looping strategy to get streaks out of an array.

**The Challenge:** To reduce an array's elements without looping through it explicitly.
**The Input:** All integers from -10 to 10 (except 0) ordered randomly.
**The Desired Output:** An array representing streaks of positive or negative numbers. For instance, a -3 represents three consecutive negative numbers.  A 2 represents two consecutive positive numbers.

Sample script:

```
original_array = (-10..10).to_a.sort{rand(3)-1}
original_array.reject!{|i| i == 0} # remove zero

streaks = (-1..1).to_a # this is a placeholder.  
# The streaks array will contain the output.
# Your code goes here, hopefully without looping through the array

puts "Original Array:"
puts original_array.join(",")
puts "Streaks:"
puts streaks.join(",")
puts "Streaks Sum:"
puts streaks.inject{|sum,n| sum + n}
```

Sample outputs:

```
Original Array:
3,-4,-6,1,-10,-5,7,-8,9,-3,-7,8,10,4,2,5,-2,6,-1,-9
Streaks:
1,-2,1,-2,1,-1,1,-2,5,-1,1,-2
Streaks Sum:
0


Original Array:
-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Streaks:
-10,10
Streaks Sum:
0
```

Note a few things:

- The streaks array has alternating positive and negative values.
- The sum of the elements streaks array is always 0 (as is the sum of the original).
- The sum of the absolute values of the streak array is always 20.

Hope that's clear!

**Edit:** I do realize that such constructs as reject! are actually looping through the array in the background. I'm not excluding looping because I'm a mean person. Just looking to learn about the language.  If explicit iteration is necessary, that's fine.

Comment: Why not iterate through the array?  How do you expect to process the contents of an array without looping through it.  Even if you use a method to do this, it will still loop through the array internally.

Comment: you do realize that every method you called in your code example was in fact looping through the array...

Comment: Yeah exactly, there's no way to a reduce an array without looping through it... there'd be no way to access the content.

Comment: I think he want an elegant way where looping is abstracted into something more meaningful and simpler. It's a matter of elegant code, not of big-Oh.

Comment: Then extend `Array` with a method that does this.  There is no built in ruby method that will do all this.

Comment: If you just want to hide the looping, how about calling a method with the looping hidden inside your method?  Designing for "Elegance" is, in my experience, just about always going to lead to worse results--I cringe whenever I hear that word these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ruby 1.9 there's a much simpler way to solve this problem:

```
original_array.chunk{|x| x <=> 0 }.map{|a,b| a * b.size }
```

[Enumerable.chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) will group all consecutive elements of an array together by the output of a block:

```
>> original_array.chunk{|x| x <=> 0 }
=> [[1, [3]], [-1, [-4, -6]], [1, [1]], [-1, [-10, -5]], [1, [7]], [-1, [-8]], [1, [9]], [-1, [-3, -7]], [1, [8, 10, 4, 2, 5]], [-1, [-2]], [1, [6]], [-1, [-1, -9]]]
```

This is almost exactly what OP asks for, except the resulting groups need to be counted up to get the final streaks array.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was originally looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Well, here's a one-line version, if that pleases you more:

```
streaks = original_array.inject([]) {|a,x| (a.empty? || x * a[-1] < 0 ? a << 0 : a)[-1] += x <=> 0; a}
```

And if even inject is too loopy for you, here's a really silly way:

```
  streaks = eval "[#{original_array.join(",").gsub(/((\-\d+,?)+|(\d+,?)+)/) {($1[0..0] == "-" ? "-" : "") + $1.split(/,/).size.to_s + ","}}]"
```

But I think it's pretty clear that you're better off with something much more straightforward:

```
streaks = []
original_array.each do |x|
  xsign = (x <=> 0)
  if streaks.empty? || x * streaks[-1] < 0
    streaks << xsign
  else
    streaks[-1] += xsign
  end
end
```

In addition to being much easier to understand and maintain, the "loop" version runs in about two-thirds the time of the inject version, and about a sixth of the time of the eval/regexp one.

PS: Here's one more potentially interesting version:

```
a = [[]]
original_array.each do |x|
  a << [] if x * (a[-1][-1] || 0) < 0
  a[-1] << x
end
streaks = a.map {|aa| (aa.first <=> 0) * aa.size}
```

This uses two passes, first building an array of streak arrays, then converting the array of arrays to an array of signed sizes. In Ruby 1.8.5, this is actually slightly faster than the inject version above (though in Ruby 1.9 it's a little slower), but the boring loop is still the fastest.

Comment: Could use a comment or two. I get that you explained it, but putting comments in the code is something that is often neglected.

Answer (score 6):

```
new_array = original_array.dup
<Squeegy's answer, using new_array>
```

Ta da! No looping through the original array. Although inside dup it's a MEMCPY, which I suppose might be considered a loop at the assembler level?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/array_8c-source.html

**EDIT:** ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
original_array.each do |num|
  if streaks.size == 0
    streaks << num
  else
    if !((streaks[-1] > 0) ^ (num > 0))
      streaks[-1] += 1
    else
      streaks << (num > 0 ? 1 : -1)
    end
  end
end
```

The magic here is the `^` xor operator.

```
true ^ false  #=> true
true ^ true   #=> false
false ^ false #=> false
```

So if the last number in the array is on the same side of zero as the number being processed, then add it to the streak, otherwise add it to the streaks array to start a new streak.  Note that sine `true ^ true` returns `false` we have to negate the whole expression.

Comment: This doesn't look correct to me.  Are you counting or summing?

Comment: Oops, I slightly misundertood.  This sums the values, in the streak not counts them.  You're right.  I''ll fix it.

Comment: Thank you!  This was helpful.  The XOR solution is great. I voted you up even if I accepted the other answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

More string abuse, a la Glenn McDonald, only different:

```
runs = original_array.map do |e|
  if e < 0
    '-'
  else
    '+'
  end
end.join.scan(/-+|\++/).map do |t|
  "#{t[0..0]}#{t.length}".to_i
end

p original_array
p runs
# => [2, 6, -4, 9, -8, -3, 1, 10, 5, -7, -1, 8, 7, -2, 4, 3, -5, -9, -10, -6]
# => [2, -1, 1, -2, 3, -2, 2, -1, 2, -4]
```